# Can google analytics track # (URL fragment) in url?

Tags: google-analytics

In one of my url, `www.mycompany.com/accounts`, I show different content based on the hash. e.g.  `www.mycompany.com/accounts#profile` shows user profile and  `www.mycompany.com/accounts#subscription` shows the current subscription of the current user. It is implemented with Backbone.

When I search for `www.mycompany.com/accounts#profile`, I yield nothing. I am pretty sure this url is accessed by different users every day.

[image]

Is it a limitation of google analytics? If so, how can I track this sort of behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you're looking for is URL fragment, i.e. anything after the # symbol.

Google Analytics [does not track it by default](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews), from what I understand, although I can't find actual GA documentation confirming this.

> In Google Analytics, fragment changes are not tracked by default, and the URL paths that are passed to GA with your Pageview hits are stripped of these fragments. With Google Tag Manager, this can be remedied with a History Change Trigger and some Variable magic.

Thus, `www.mycompany.com/accounts#profile` is tracked as `www.mycompany.com/accounts` and hits aggregated with the same URLs with different fragments.

The link above has some useful tips as to how to get fragment tracking working.

Comment: turpachull's answer above is absolutely correct. URL fragments are not automatically tracked with GA. However, you can track those "virtual pageviews" if you use Google Tag Manager. You will have to create a custom variable to track the fragments as pageviews.

Comment: Tracking "virtual pageviews" is a built-in feature of GA, but you have to configure it, here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages  (apparently, `allowAnchor` is built-in as well), Google Tag Manager just makes it easier to implement.